# How to make ListView Clickable and delete data from mysql database?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, clickable

```
package com.yiqiexample.cc;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.HashMap;    
import org.json.JSONArray;    
import org.json.JSONException;    
import org.json.JSONObject;    
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.app.ListActivity;    
import android.app.ProgressDialog;    
import android.content.Intent;    
import android.os.AsyncTask;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;    
import android.widget.AdapterView;    
import android.widget.Button;    
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;    
import android.widget.ListAdapter;    
import android.widget.ListView;    
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;    
//import android.widget.ImageView;    
import android.widget.TextView;    
import android.widget.Toast;    
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;    
public class Food extends ListActivity 
    implements OnClickListener {

    // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //testing on Emulator:
     private static final String READ_COMMENTS_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/pbda2/foodordered.php";
    // my ip add 192.168.43.176
     //private CheckBox chkFood, chkDrinks, chkServices;
      //private Button btnDisplay, chkClear, deliever, chkClearFood, fooddeliever, drinksdeliever, servicesdeliever, chkClearDrinks, chkClearServices;
      //private TextView clearThis,orderdisplay, clearThisFood, foodorderdisplay, drinksorderdisplay, servicesorderdisplay, clearThisDrinks, clearThisServices;

      private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
      private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
        private static final String TAG_SEATNUMBER = "seatnumber";
        private static final String TAG_FOODORDERED = "foodordered";
        //it's important to note that the message is both in the parent branch of 
        //our JSON tree that displays a "Post Available" or a "No Post Available" message,
        //and there is also a message for each individual post, listed under the "posts"
        //category, that displays what the user typed as their message.

      //An array of all of our comments
        private JSONArray mComments = null;
        //manages all of our comments in a list.
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;      

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.food);



        View v = findViewById(R.id.backmain);
        //set event listener
            v.setOnClickListener(this);

            View z = findViewById(R.id.drinksbtn);
            //set event listener
                z.setOnClickListener(this);

                View x = findViewById(R.id.servicebtn);
                //set event listener
                    x.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {

        // Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
        // we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
        // to the json element name, and the content, for example,
        // message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Bro, it's time to power up the J parser 
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
        //back a JSON object.  Boo-yeah Jerome.
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_COMMENTS_URL);

        //when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
        //try to catch any exceptions:
        try {

            //I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
            //before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
            //mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
            //available
            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                //gets the content of each tag
                String seatnumber = c.getString(TAG_SEATNUMBER);
                String foodordered = c.getString(TAG_FOODORDERED);



                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_SEATNUMBER, seatnumber);
                map.put(TAG_FOODORDERED, foodordered);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);

                //annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }









    @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.backmain){
            //define a new Intent for the second Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

            //start the second Activity
            this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.drinksbtn){
            //define a new Intent for the second Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Drinks.class);

            //start the second Activity
            this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.servicebtn){
            //define a new Intent for the second Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Services.class);

            //start the second Activity
            this.startActivity(intent);
            }



    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {
        // For a ListActivity we need to set the List Adapter, and in order to do
        //that, we need to create a ListAdapter.  This SimpleAdapter,
        //will utilize our updated Hashmapped ArrayList, 
        //use our single_post xml template for each item in our list,
        //and place the appropriate info from the list to the
        //correct GUI id.  Order is important here.

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.single_comment, new String[] { TAG_SEATNUMBER, TAG_FOODORDERED
                //TAG_DRINKSORDERED, TAG_SERVICES
                         }, new int[] { R.id.seatnumber, R.id.orders
                //R.id.drinkstv, R.id.servicestv,


         });



        // I shouldn't have to comment on this one:
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // Optional: when the user clicks a list item we 
        //could do something.  However, we will choose
        //to do nothing...
        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // This method is triggered if an item is click within our
                // list. For our example we won't be using this, but
                // it is useful to know in real life applications.

                //new!

            // selected item 
                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);
                //end new lines!!




            }
        });
    }   




    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Food.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading orders...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //we will develop this method in version 2
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
          //we will develop this method in version 2
            updateList();
        }
    }

}
```

single_item.java

```
package com.yiqiexample.cc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
        // displaying selected product name
        txtProduct.setText(product);

    }
}
```

single_list_item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/product_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

food.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android1:id="@+id/bg2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:background="#E0FFFF" >

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android1:text="@string/delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/servicebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="358dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/foodbutton"
        android:text="SERVICES" />

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/drinksbtn"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android1:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android1:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android1:text="DRINKS ORDERS" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/foodtitle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_layover"
        android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/servicesdelivered"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android1:clickable="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layover"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android1:id="@+id/backmain"
                android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android1:text="@string/backtomain" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/servicesdelivered"
        android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android1:layout_above="@+id/drinksbtn"
        android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android1:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
        android1:text="@string/servicesdelivered"
        android1:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I tried to click on the listview, 
it appears an error  -

> error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

I need help with making the listview clickable and it will intent into a page where I can delete specific data.

Comment: you are not posting right code!! where is listview in your code please post proper xml layout and java code

Comment: @Hardik i've edited with the listview xml codes.

Comment: your layout not contain any <ListView> tag

Comment: @Hardik the java code? i'm sorry i'm new to android programming do you mind telling me how should i edit it?

Comment: you are again posting wrong code it should be <ListView> instaed <TextView> in single_list_item_view.xml

Comment: use a simple adapter class.

Comment: here is an example http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Comment: @Hardik so i should put the <ListView> code into single_list_item_view.xml?

Comment: @RanjitPati do u mind telling me how should i edit?

Comment: you first see the example url which i post

Comment: @Hardik alright i will try ur url now.

Comment: @Hardik my listview are from my database is it still possible to use ur url as a guide?

Comment: yes you can just different is that in url, data is static, and your come from database

Comment: @Hardik do u also happen to have a url that teaches how to delete a specific line from the listview when click?

Comment: here is url that teaches how to delete record from listview http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/08/delete-row-item-in-listview-android.html

Comment: @Hardik may i know how to change the string list view to database list view?

Answer (score 3):

```
 define Listview and Myadapter,DatabaseConnection class  globaly 

 adapter

private ListView listview;
private Myadapter adapter;
private DatabaseConnection databaseconnection;

and in oncreate



   listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

   databaseconnection=new DatabaseConnection(this);

   adapter=new Myadapter(this,list);         //  list means pass record as list and create 
    custom adapter thats best way


    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
      //do something here like-


       here get the id of record from list using listview position and 
        detete record from database using dis id

      databaseconnection.open();            //create the database object first
      deleteRecord(int id);             //pass id for delete that record
      databaseconnection.close();



    }
 });
```

Comment: hi, do you know how to convert a normal type in listview into a database listview? http://androidforbegineers.blogspot.in/2013/08/delete-row-item-in-listview-android.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code you still not use the list view.First define it globally like

```
private ListView mList;
```

Then initialize inside onCreate() like:

```
   mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
   mList.setAdapter(your_adapter) //this adapter contains the mCommentList arraylist
   mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
   {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
      //do something here
    }
 });
```

Its good if you use an adapter class to set value in your custom layout.
[Check this example](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

Thank you

Comment: where does (your_adapter) comes from?